# How to select all strips in a channel via python?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

How to select all strips in a channel via python, and deselect everything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Set `strip.select` to True if `strip.channel` is "active channel".**

Test Script with  `active_channel = 1`. Note I've simply set the active strip to None if it is not in the desired "active channel".  Change this to suit.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

active_channel = 1

sed = scene.sequence_editor
# if active strip isn't in active_channel set to None.
if getattr(sed.active_strip, "channel", -1) != active_channel:
    sed.active_strip = None

sequences = sed.sequences_all
# select all strips in active channel
for strip in sequences:
    strip.select = strip.channel == active_channel
```